# How can one configure an Upwork Enterprise account so that one cannot overspend a purchase order?

Tags: upwork

Job posts in an Upwork Enterprise account are linked to a purchase order. How can one configure an Upwork Enterprise account so that one cannot overspend a purchase order? That'd be a very convenient safety guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, one cannot configure an Upwork Entreprise account so that one cannot overspend a purchase order. Upwork doesn't have that feature. I assume this is because Upwork takes a 15% fee on all payments (not counting the fees that Upwork on the freelancer side).